# Flex Spark VGroup, bring item to top of display list without changing order

Tags: apache-flex

When using the spark vGroup to lay out elements, the item at the bottom of the list is always at the top of the display stack. I need to have an item at the top of the list be at the top of the display stack as well, so that items belong to it (which are being dragged around the screen) lay over the other elements. I tried laying them out and using the setElementIndex function to bring it to the top of the display stack, but that resorts the list being resorted and the item moving to the bottom, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Use the `depth` attribute

Comment: @RIAstar even though its a one liner, you should post that as the answer :)

Comment: @SunilD. A four-worder, more like ;)  Or two actually: I tried "use depth", but SO wouldn't take it.

Comment: @SunilD. FYI: apparently an answer must contain at least 30 characters. Now you know ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `IVisualItem`s have a [depth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IVisualElement.html#depth) property which determines the order in which they are rendered.
Setting `depth="1"` on one of the items should have it rendered in front of the others.